# Plot from .csv file

Tags: plotting

I have a .csv file which contains the values of 1 parameter from a measured  biological sample. Those values are ordered in the rows and columns in the excel file corresponding to the measured point on the sample (so the position of the value in the excel file is also the measured position on the sample). I now want to create a colorplot of this sample so that I can see how the regions(=parameter values) vary within the sample. Since I'm totally not into computing, I wanted to ask if anyone of you can give me some input of how to do this in Mathematica? 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you want to use the CSV or the Excel file? Further, do we assume that you have one value of the parameter in each cell of the spreadsheet, and the cell coordinates are the coordinates in the sample?

Comment: It would be helpful that you provide the CSV file...

Comment: I agree, having the CSV file would help. I would think something in the direction: `ArrayPlot[Import["filename.csv","Table"]]` would be what you want.

Comment: ok so this is a small overview sample, the csv file looks like this: 5,,45,,,,78,
23,,45,,78,,,
3,43,,,,67,,
3,,5,,,,6,
,13,,,76,,,
,56,,,,,,67
45,,,65,,54,,
,56,56,45,,,,
4,,6767,65,56,56,56,
,56,34,456,6,,,
567,56,45,34,5653,,,
,,65,23,65,,,78
,,45,45,6,,,
65,,,756,,,,
,,,,,,,
54,34,,78,65,65,78,
,,,435,78,5,65,65
,656,,,,,, so if you import that in excel and do a comma separation on the data you can see that some cells have a value and some cells are empty, this corresponds directly to the regions where we were able to measure a parameter and where not, so the single cell directly correspon

Comment: @BCFC don't use answers as comments/edits.

Comment: @BCFC what are the dimensions of the sample you've provided?